# JCheckBox en un ButtonGroup saber cual esta seleccionado (java)

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo un buttonGroup con 3 `jCheckBox` y quiero saber cual de ellos esta seleccionado para poder usarlo en una configuración.

este es el `group`:

```
ButtonGroup columnas = new ButtonGroup();

columnas.add(checkBox);
```

este el el `checkbox`:

```
JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("2");

checkBox.setBounds(45, 181, 51, 25);

checkBox.addChangeListener(this);

contentPane.add(checkBox);
```

y este es el método que atiene el `listener`:

```
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e){

        if (checkBox.isSelected()==true){

            nivel = 2;

        }
```

la clase principal implementa `ChangeListener`, pero cuando entro en la ventana y hace click en una de las `jCheckBox` me tira este error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at graficaa.Configuracion.stateChanged(Configuracion.java:128)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireStateChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.stateChanged(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireStateChanged(Unknown Source)
```

alguna sugerencia?

gracias a todos

Comment: Para qué meter un jCheckBox en un ButtonGroup? Porque los ButtonGroup que yo sepa solo se utilizan en RadioButtons. Que necesitas hacer?

Comment: esto no es válido, por favor no uses la zona de respuestas para hacer preguntas o comentarios, espera a tener la reputación necesaria para dejar comentarios

Comment: puede que ese sea mi error, como tenia toda la pantalla armada con jCheckBox pensé que podría armar el grupo con esos, necesito seleccionar una opcion de varias y con los jCheckBox  podía seleccionar varias por eso los puse en un group